# curr_item doesn't seem to be right?

Tags: memcached

I'm using a simple lua program to do a batch insert, the expire time of each item was set to 86400 seconds, which **won't get expired for** the whole day.

Right now I have 1,000,000 curr_items, but if I dump them with memcached-tools, and grep for '^add', I got only 27235 items

```
%> memcached-tool 127.0.0.1:11211 display
  #  Item_Size  Max_age   Pages   Count   Full?  Evicted Evict_Time OOM
  8     480B         4s     464 1012907      no        0        0    0

%> memcached-tool 127.0.0.1:11211 dump | grep ^add -c                                                                                                                         
Dumping memcache contents
  Number of buckets: 1
  Number of items  : 1012907
Dumping bucket 8 - 1012907 total items
27235

%> memcached-tool 127.0.0.1:11211 stats | egrep '(curr|bytes)'
                   bytes   447704894
              bytes_read   407765187
           bytes_written    78574999
        curr_connections          10
              curr_items     1012907
          limit_maxbytes  2147483648
```

I need this to estimate possible memory need for my system, but now I'm not sure about the item count, which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there's hard limit on cachedump, which is 2M as in the mailing list.

That's what stopped the tool from dumping more keys.